# Error en /home/hortifre/public_html/wp-content/themes/applica/functions.php on line 313

Tags: php

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/hortifre/public_html/wp-content/themes/applica/inc/widgets/init.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/hortifre/public_html/wp-content/themes/applica/functions.php on line 313

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: esto es lo que me dice, pero nose que debo cambiar: require get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets/init.php';